# Подсчёт площади прямоугольника через формулу Герона в python

Tags: python

Добрый день! Знаю, название странное, сейчас объясню.
По задаче необходимо найти площадь прямоугольника через треугольники, из которых состоит этот 4-х угольник(Фото). Использовав формулу Герона я написал следующий кусок кода:

```
import math
n = int(input())
cor = []
for i in range(0,n):
    cor.append(input())


g = list(map(int,cor[0].split(sep=' ')))
so = 0 #Переменная для общей площади
for i in range(0, 6, 2):
    a = math.sqrt((g[2+i]-g[4+i])**2+(g[3+i]-g[5+i])**2) #Длинна сторон a,b,c
    b = math.sqrt((g[3+i]-g[0])**2+(g[3+i]-g[1])**2)
    c = math.sqrt((g[2+i]-g[0])**2+(g[3+i]-g[1])**2)
    p = (a+b+c)/2 #Полупериметр
    s = math.sqrt(math.fabs(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c)))#Площадь по формуле Герона
    so+=s
print(so)
```

Но выводится неправильная площадь!
P.S Первые два значения в списке -координаты точки-общей вершины у треугольников. Пример входных данных:
1

5 2 2 1 6 1 6 3 2 3

Ответ должен быть равным 8

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]]

Comment: Что за переменная g1?

Comment: Пардон, редактор исправил ее на ссылку. Конечно же, g[1]

Comment: отформатировали бы код, а то глаза ломать - не много желающих

Comment: Так я же и отформатировал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему ответ должен быть равен 8? Ширина 5, высота 2. Ответ 10.

У Вас входные данные не соответствуют рисунку.Вот:

1

5 2 1 1 1 3 6 3 6 1

И вводить нужно точки по порядку.

```
import math
def length(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
def square(a, b, c):
    p = (a + b + c)/2
    return math.sqrt(p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c))
n = int(input())
cor = []
for i in range(0,n):
    cor.append(input())

g = list(map(int,cor[0].split(sep=' ')))
so = 0 #Переменная для общей площади
for i in range(2, 7, 2):
    a = length(g[0], g[1], g[i], g[i + 1])
    b = length(g[0], g[1], g[i + 2], g[i + 3])
    c = length(g[i], g[i + 1], g[i + 2], g[i + 3])
    s = square(a, b, c)  # Площадь по формуле Герона
    so+=s
#Учитываем последнюю и первую точки
a = length(g[0], g[1], g[len(g) - 2], g[len(g) - 1]) 
b = length(g[0], g[1], g[2], g[3])
c = length(g[len(g) - 2], g[len(g) - 1], g[2], g[3])
s = square(a, b, c)
so+=s
print(so)
```